# Call to a member function checkAccess() on a non-object yii2

Tags: yii2, rbac

I am following http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-check to implement RBAC. When I am using this

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {
    // create post
}
```

in SiteController 's actionLogin() function

I am getting an error `Call to a member function checkAccess() on a non-object yii2`

Can you find out the way to sort it out ?
My RBAC config is

```
'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
        'itemFile' => '@app/rbac/items.php', 
        'assignmentFile' => '@app/rbac/assignments.php',  
        'ruleFile' => '@app/rbac/rules.php',  

        ],
```

I am trying to use it in site controllers's

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {



        print_r(\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost'));exit;
}}
```

Comment: Did you configure your user component ?

Comment: How ? I am not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can call \Yii::$app->user in there because the user is not logged in, hence the error.

You should check beforehand if he is a guest

```
if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest && \Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {
    // create post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your user component :

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

> The logic of how to authenticate a user should be done in the class implementing yii\web\IdentityInterface. You are also required to set $identityClass with the name of this class.
>
> User is configured as an application component in yii\web\Application by default. You can access that instance via Yii::$app->user.
>
> You can modify its configuration by adding an array to your application config under components as it is shown in the following example:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', // User must implement the IdentityInterface
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    // 'loginUrl' => ['user/login'],
    // ...
]
```

Comment: user component is configured like this only